# When I receive a reply to an exchange email, the gmail notifications show my original message, not the reply

Tags: gmail

I'm having a really odd problem with my Nexus 5X.  I had the problem when I got it (marshmellow) and it still persists when upgraded to nougat.

When I send out an email on my desktop computer, and someone replies to it, i'll see the notification pop up on my phone.  However, the notification shows the text of my original email, not the text of the reply. I have to tap the notification to open the gmail app and see the actual reply.  This is very frustrating because i cannot "at a glance" see what the email is, and instead have to open it, marking it read, which will mess with my flow on the desktop client.

Has anyone else run into this problem?  Anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do nothing... The problem is in Gmail's app. You must wait for future upgrades/updates or you can send an email to Gmail's developer.

Comment: It didn't used to do this, however.  I believe the problem started when I upgraded from the nexus 5 to nexus 5X.  Is it a hardware issue?

Answer (score 0):

A work around is to deactivate "conversation view" in the Gmail general preferences. It solves it but you loose the conversation grouping of emails